# The primitive root of modulo 109

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots

While trying to find the first primitive root of modulo 109, I've ran across a very weird problem. Firstly I used Euler Criterion to try to find a number that would satisfy $a^{(p-1)/2}≡-1$ mod($p$). Hence $\phi(109)=108$, thus I was looking for $a^{54}≡1$ mod($109$). When checking $2$ for this relationship, it appears to satisfy it as $2^{54}≡108$ mod($109$). This was calculated using $mod$ function in Matlab. However, when I use Matlab and other online sources to find the first primitive root for my calculation they say it is $6$.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^{36}$ is already $1$ mod $109$. So it can't be a primitive root. Just because $2^{54}=-1$, that's not enough. You'd need $54$ to be the smallest power for which $2^n$ is $-1$. But this happens with $2^{18}$.

Comment: Thanks :) Then why when I check $6^{108}$ its not congruent to $1$ mod($109$)

Comment: @loler2654 It is for me. How are you making that check?

Comment: using Matlab function $mod(X,Y)$ where $X$ is $a$ and $Y$ is $n$ for $a≡x (n)$

Comment: @loler2654 you shouldn't even need to check; 109 is prime...

Comment: I don't know Matlab. Without opening a CAS, I just had Excel do this. I put `6` in a cell. Below that, `=MOD(6*<previous cell>,109)`, and extended down 108 cells. This simulates what it would be like to multiply by 6 and reduce one factor at a time. And it gives $6^{108}\equiv 1$. Incidentally, doing this with $2$s instead of $6$s revealed quickly the powers of $2$ mentioned in this answer.

Comment: There was something wrong with the Matlab $mod$ function